# Matlab path tool refuses to save pathdef.m

Tags: matlab

I've just installed matlab 2019a and keep getting the same error where Matlab says it cannot save the pathdef.m file because it's write protected. When i choose to save to another location, and press close it keeps coming with the same question to store the pathdef.m elsewhere...? Is this a bug in 2019a?

Comment: Did you try removing the write restrictions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a whole other issue... I tried to add a toolbox with too many items... that caused pathdef.m to freeze... now it's all working fine!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in Ubuntu 18.04 but I managed to fix it. This is what I did:

Find prefdir location by typing `prefdir` into MATLAB command window. In my case:

```
/home/myusername/.matlab/R2019a
```

So I did the following in Ubuntu terminal:

```
sudo chown -R myusername /home/myusername/.matlab/R2019a
```

Comment: I work with windows 10...? Anyway to perform this operation on command line?

Comment: I last used Win7, but maybe Win10 is similar: you could try and find the pathdef.m file on your hard drive, right click it, select properties (i think) and remove write protection